# React TS Axios using local JSON api

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, api, axios

I am trying to connect a test JSON server to my frontend react using axios. I see the objects in the Network inspect, but nothing displays to the site.

I'm thinking it may be something with the mapping? when I removed ? I get an error in the console. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" The status code reads 200 and I see the preview and response. I'm super new to Typescript and React so I'm not really sure what the issue is. Thanks for understanding!

testapi

```
import axios from "axios";
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/",
  method: "GET",
});
```

useTest

```
import { CanceledError } from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import testapi from "./api-client";

export interface Title {
  title_id: number;
  title_name: string;
  title_description: string;
}

interface FetchTitleResponse {
  count: number;
  results: Title[];
}

const useTest = () => {
  const [titles, setTitles] = useState<Title[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();

    testapi
      .get<FetchTitleResponse>("/titles", { signal: controller.signal })
      .then((res) => setTitles(res.data.results))
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err instanceof CanceledError) return;
        setError(err.message);
      });
    return () => controller.abort();
  }, []);
  return { titles, error };
};

export default useTest;
```

app

```
import useTest from "./useTest";

function App() {
  const { titles, error } = useTest();

  return (
    <div>
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      hi
      <ul>
        {titles?.map((title) => (
          <li key={title.title_id}>{title.title_name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[JSON example. I'm mainly just trying to see if I can connect to a JSON file before my group mate finishes the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIrcH.png)

[objects show in network preview, and heading is reading 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAnjA.png)

[response image, Note: on the JSON I changed the name from titles to results with no luck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh2V8.png)

Comment: Can you provide the actual JSON that comes back with the call to: `http://localhost:3000/titles`?

Comment: Sure, should have included it from the beginning.  going to edit the main post with an image.

Comment: Everything looks OK. Start by logging stuff tot he console in various places to see if code is being reached. You can also replace the actual API call with `Promise.resolve(mockData)` so you know if you get the JSON you expect the code works as intended.

Comment: When I make a new function in the app.tsx file, ```const promise1 = Promise.resolve(titles);
promise1.then((value) => { console.log(value); });``` it shows the array as 0, so potentially something with the JSON itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears and runs correctly. Please make sure your response looks like this:

```js
// where res.data =>
{
  count: number,
  results: [{
    title_id: number,
    title_name: string,
    title_description: string
  }]
}
```

#### Edit

In regards to the following line,

```
.then((res) => setTitles(res.data.results))
```

The `res.data` is the complete response payload from GET request (an object). The subsequent access to `results` (object array) is a named property of the response object.

Please review the example structure below. This is what the "Response" tab in Chrome should be displaying. It ***should not*** be a simple array of title objects.

#### Example

```json
// GET http://localhost:3000/titles (response)
{
  "count": 2,
  "results": [
    {
      "title_id": 1,
      "title_name": "Foo",
      "title_description": "Foo..."
    },
    {
      "title_id": 2,
      "title_name": "Bar",
      "title_description": "Bar..."
    }
  ]
}
```

The `results` should not be `null`. It looks like you are already guarding against `null` with optional chaining:

```
<ul>
  {titles?.map((title) => (
    <li key={title.title_id}>{title.title_name}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

I suspect that your top-level `results` key is not actually an array.

Comment: It is probably something I did with the JSON, because the code I'm using was referenced from a tutorial that calls from an actual API.

Comment: Ah, so I added titles to the top most level and left results under which seemed to work. Thanks!!